# How is meditation and concentration done in Islam?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, spirituality

How is meditation and concentration done in Islam to increase the focus and get calmness and peace in heart?
How to do concentration on God, Allah in Islam to be strong from inside, get peace and be more productive and active?
How are this things done is Islam?
As I've seen in some internet pages, that this meditation and concentration is not considered as halal in Islam.

Comment: see these https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmgAkaHFZY8&t=298s  and http://www.nurmuhammad.com/pbuh/?p=3146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Islam is a religion. Sharia (the laws) does not stop you to seek health benefit from Yoga, Tai'Chi or any other means that does not goes agains the tawheed (oneness of Allah).

The meditation usually practice by muslims are zikr, it sound based meditation. There are differnt ways according to different sufi tariqua. If you are spiritually incline and feel strong love for Allah (sw) then you should seek sufi teacher, who practice Islam and does not do harmful innovation. But if you just want to relax, you can do mindful meditations, there are lot of apps now that help in mindful meditation or just a grab book from local library.