# Is there any meditation and spirituality guided in Islam?

Tags: spirituality

Although there is a suggestion to find a Sufi teacher in the answer
https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39348/51761 , I am looking for if Islam (Quran and Hadiths etc) suggests or mentions any ways to meditate, mindfulnes, gratitude, spirituality, concentration, feeling connected with God or universe, etc.  other than just prayers and chants.

P.S. I am a spiritually inclined person. What does Islam suggests about me?

Update: @Muhammad Haneef's answer says there is not as such any thing as meditation in Islam. But if a Muslim practices some other sort of meditation (such as nowadays mindfulness meditation used in mainstream therapeutic psychology) does Islam forbids that practice? Or if a Muslim learns Yoga or some other sort of meditation, does the religion restricts him or her for doing so? Would it be seen as trying to modify or add on over the Quran? or these will be seen as just some permissible secular techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the preceding answer of Muhammad Haneef. Concerning the value of practice, in a nutshell:

***Salat*** is certainly the most significant spiritual exercise that goes back to Muhammad (p b.u.h). It's our reminder, our steady spiritual link to the Most Holy.

***Dua*** is the individual spiritual exercise: You bring your own concerns before God. You get conscious of what is important to your life, reflect your errors and your whishes of your own and others. Dua has already been done by Jews and Christians before but it is a confirmed of Islam.

***Other Islamic*** spiritual practice has been developed by believers (including, but not restricted to Sufism) which are not equal to the aforementioned, not accepted by Salafiya and discouraged by some Orthodox scholars but often (unfortunately not always) good and acceptable.

***Non-Islamic*** practice is rejected in Salafiya and mostly tolerated but discouraged by Orthodox scholars as long as it does not interfere with our belief.

Any foreign practice that arose from shirk is forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Bismillah
No Meditation in islam because we have something better than mediatation, which is the shalat. Of course teaches all that good character, because islam is a perfect religion.
• Islam teaches mindfulnes, that we always mindful of Allah wherever we are. In surah ali 'imran verse 190-191:
190. "Indeed, in the creation of the heavens and the earth and the alternation of the day and night there are signs for people of reason."
191. ˹They are˺ those who remember Allah while standing, sitting, and lying on their sides, and reflect on the creation of the heavens and the earth ˹and pray˺, “Our Lord! You have not created ˹all of˺ this without purpose. Glory be to You! Protect us from the torment of the Fire

• Islam teaches gratitude.
The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, would say when he retired to his bed, “All praise is due to Allah who has fed us, given us drink, sufficed us, and sheltered us. How many are those who do not have enough and have no shelter?”
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2715

- Concentration.
  In surah al araf verse 205:
  And remember your Lord within yourself in humility and in fear without being apparent in speech - in the mornings and the evenings. And do not be among the heedless.

Heedless means taking little or no notice; dont even care about the hereafter, and about halal and haram. Otherwise, we should always concentrate on what Allah told us to do, on what pleases Him.

• Islam teaches to feel connected with God and knowing that we are just a small part of this universe.
When we are doing prayer, we say:
"Allahu akbar", means Allah is the greatest and I am His small creature who needs Him in every aspect of my life"

Then we say:
"Alhamdu Lillahi Rabbil Alamin"
Means praise be to Allah, the Lord of the Universe, And I am a part of universe.

Shalat Is the way human connect to their creator, Allah. So it is not just movement of body, but we put our heart into it by deeply understanding what we read in the shalah.

That's why muslim should keep always learning about islam so they will know better about this beautiful religion :)

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for your insights and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah

Scholars said yoga is haram, as you can read in this link:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/101591/what-is-the-ruling-on-yoga

Any muslim tried to follow path other than the path of prophet muhammad -peace be upon him- will be lost and misguided. Some people tried yoga and Jinn Shaitan enter to his body.

If we want to be healthy or physically strong, go excercise, do sport.
If we want to be an objective person, learn islam because islam is the truth and one of Allah's name is Al-Haqq.
If we want to be smart, learn ushool al-fiqh or memorize the quran, or learn math or learn programming.

Psychology is product of jew. It told us to believe in our self, not believe in Allah.
It told us to feel enough by ourself, while in islam we are taugh to always feel not enough because or deed is so small in front of Allah. Resulting we become more humble, soft hearted and have yaqeen in our heart. While the people who learn psychology and meditatation will become arrogant and always full of doubt in life.

Hope that answer the question.

Comment: Scholars said... Islamqa.info is a Salafiya site. It represents Salafiya positions. Psychology is not only Jewish, and Jews believe in God. It is possible to study how our emotions work and believe but we should measure approaches in Psychology by our belief, and not all approaches will pass.